# Notepad ++ regexp search

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have several documents with hundred lines as below, the intention is to search using wild characters and ignore the lines that have simple quote ' before Browser in any way, it can be the first character of the line, several spaces or tab first then Browser, but all lines containing ' before Browser means the line is commented and must be ignored. Also All the lines that contains Browser but doesn't have simple quote before browser needs to be part of the results. I have accomplish just to find lines that start with Browser alone, but not the ones that start with spaces nor Tabs and then Browser without including the ones that have simple quote. Below is the search line I am using:

^(Browser.*Image\("Click to go to the next.*"\).Click.*)

Sample lines below:

```
Browser("sample").Image("Click to go to the next").Click ' comments
     Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY").Image("Click to go to the next").Click 'test
 Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY").Image("Click to go to the next").Click
 Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY").Image("Click to go to the next_6").Click 563,41
               Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY_3").Image("Click to go to the next").Click
Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY").Image("Click to go to the next").Click 525,55
'Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY_5").Image("Click to go to the next").Click        
'        Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY").Image("Click to go to the next").Click    
      '         Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY").Image("Click to go to the next").Click 

    '     Browser("sample").Page("sample_2").Frame("BODY").Image("Click to go to the next_4").Click
```

Comment: Why not just put horizontal space `\h` between `^` and `browser`: [`^\h*(Browser...`](https://regex101.com/r/7Pgj7k/1) (no single quotes can occure). If you need to start the match at `Browser` try [like this with `\K`](https://regex101.com/r/vS6N7t/1).

Comment: Please format your sample lines so that they are clear.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank you, the solution you provided met my requirement. 